# How to count running threads in ruby server

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sinatra

I want to do a 'long running' - (takes about 0.5 seconds to execute) task in a thread in a Sinatra web server.

The web response takes about 20 ms, so if I get busy then threads will pile up...

So I was thinking that I would do it synch if I get busy..

```
if (running_thread_count > 10)
    stuff_that_takes_a_second()
else
    Thread.new do
        stuff_that_takes_a_second()
    end
end
```

How do you get the number of running threads (I want the the number of threads launched, and not done running yet) - how do you code running_thread_count?

```
def running_thread_count
 return Thread.list.count
end
```

Or do I need to check for threads that are running? i.e. when a thread is finished running, will it stop coming back in the Thread.list?

I don't want to call join as that would defeat the purpose - which is to return quickly unless we are backed up with lots of threads working.

Comment: But without `join`, all the threads exit if one of them completes execution. `Thread.list.count` gets the number of threads that are running currently. `Thread` has a method called `status` which returns `"sleep"` or `"run"` for threads under process. I've added the code as an answer.

Comment: I thought that a ruby program running as a web server kept running all the time, so that a thread started during a web request would run to its completion?

Comment: You have a point there. Will experiment more. Thank you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This will give the count of threads that are having the status of "run" and not "sleep"

```
def running_thread_count
  Thread.list.select {|thread| thread.status == "run"}.count
end
```